# How to make the controller data override view controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

To build a sidebar that has a lot of dynamic data on it I learned about View composers in Laravel. The problem was that View Composers trigger when the view loads, overriding any data from the controller for variables with the same name. According to the Laravel 5.4 documentation though, I achieve what I want with view creators :

> View creators are very similar to view composers; however, they are
>   executed immediately after the view is instantiated instead of waiting
>   until the view is about to render. To register a view creator, use the
>   creator method:

From what I understand, this means if I load variables with the same name in the controller and the creator, controller should override it. However this isn't happening with my code. The view composer:

```
    public function boot()
{
    view()->creator('*', function ($view) {

            $userCompanies = auth()->user()->company()->get();
            $currentCompany = auth()->user()->getCurrentCompany();

        $view->with(compact('userCompanies', 'currentCompany'));
    });
}
```

And here is one of the controllers, for example:

```
    public function name()
{
    $currentCompany = (object) ['name' => 'creating', 'id' => '0', 'account_balance' => 'N/A'];

    return view('companies.name', compact('currentCompany'));
}
```

the $currentCompany variable in question, for example, always retains the value from the creator rather than being overridden by the one from the controller. Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I realized my initial assumption that the data from the view creator can be overwritten by the data from the controller was wrong. The creator still loads after the controller somehow. But I found a simple solution.

For those who want to use View composers/creators for default data that can get overwritten, do an array merge between the controller and composer/creator data at the end of the boot() method of the composer/creator, like so:

```
$with = array_merge(compact('userCompanies', 'currentCompany', 'currentUser'), $view->getData());
            $view->with($with);
```